# Magento 2 : Change color in magento add to cart button

Tags: magento2

How can I change color **add to cart** button in Magento 2 ??

Comment: You want to change color of add to cart button , right ?

Comment: yes I want to change color add to cart button

Comment: One way is overriding your styles in your custom theme at this location 
="\app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\web\css\source\_extend.less"

Comment: ok manoj  sir I will try

Comment: Any solution worked for you ?

Comment: no this solution is not working

Comment: you know you have to write CSS for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add your css:**

```
.action.primary.tocart {
    background: #222;
    border-color: #222;
    color : #fff;
}
```

Comment: hello i am creating _extend.less file in app/design/frontent/magestore/sample/magento_theme/web/css/source/_extent.less file and i am adding your code but button color is not change

Comment: Can you run this commands 

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US 
deploy as store wise like en_US
php bin/magento cache:flush